# Inverting the solutions of Pell's equations

Tags: pell-type-equations

Suppose I have a solution of a Pell's equation $y_1,x_1$, then I can find the subsequent solutions by recursively using the relation $(y_{i},x_{i})=x_{i-1}y_1+y_{i-1}x_1,x_{i-1}x_1+Dy_{i-1}y_1$ i.e. $(x_1+y_1\sqrt{D})^i$. But, if I have ONLY the $i^{th}$ solution, is there a way to get the first solution easily? It is straightforward if $i=2$, but for any number above that, if I solve by Wolfram, the expression for the solution seems to explode. So, is there an easy recursive way to get back the first solution, given the $i^{th}$ solution?

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=B+%3D+a+y+%2B+b+x,+A+%3D+ax+%2B+D+b+y) gives a clean solution. Note that the denominator is $\pm 1$.

Comment: Well, that is for $i=2$ as I mentioned in the original question. For i>2, knowing only the $i^{th}$ solution makes it a painful process to revert.

Answer (score 0):

From
$$
y_{i}=x_{i-1}y_1+y_{i-1}x_1,
\qquad
x_{i}=x_{i-1}x_1+Dy_{i-1}y_1
$$
we get
$$
x_1 = \frac{x_{i-1} x_{i} - y_{i-1} y_{i} D}{x_{i-1}^2 - y_{i-1}^2 D},
\qquad
y_1 = \frac{x_{i-1} y_{i} - x_{i} y_{i-1}}{x_{i-1}^2 - y_{i-1}^2 D}
$$
Note that the denominator is $\pm1$.

Therefore, given two consecutive solutions, we can find the first one.

If you're only given $z=x_i+y_i\sqrt{D}=(x_1+y_1\sqrt{D})^i$, then you could take the $i$-th root of $z$ and compare its fractional part with the fractional part of the integer multiples of $\sqrt{D}$. This will give $y_1$ and then $x_1$. But you may need high-precision approximation of $\sqrt{D}$.

Comment: The point is I know only the $i^{th}$ solution and nothing else. Therefore, my original question.